Need to pass linux command output as an argument to a next command
The posited syntax is roughly like this (suppose that the normal output is a json string):
final-output = my-tool action1 -j <string> | my-tool action2 -j $1 | my-tool action3 -j $1
echo $final-output

where $1 is the output of the previous command directed to the -j (json) parameter.  How would I do this?  The chaining syntax would be useful for readability.

According to your requirements, you can try something like :
initial_json="..."
intermediate_output="$(my-tool action1 -j "$initial_json")"
intermediate_output="$(my-tool action2 -j "$intermediate_output")"
final_output="$(my-tool action3 -j "$intermediate_output")"

echo "$final_output"


Converting data from input to arguments is what the xargs command is for.  If you have the GNU version of xargs, and if your program's output does not contain any null bytes, then you can do the job like this:
my-tool action1 -j <string> |
  xargs -0 my-tool action2 -j |
  xargs -0 my-tool action3 -j

You can, of course, capture that and store the result in a variable by wrapping it in a command substitution, but it's unclear to me whether you really want to do that, since the only use you suggest in the question for such a variable is to immediately print its value. For that purpose, you are better off not capturing the output in the first place.
If you have a different flavor of xargs then it might not recognize the -0 flag used above.  In that case, you could still do it in one command by using command substitution instead of piping:
  my-tool action3 -j "$(my-tool action2 -j "$(my-tool action1 -j <string>)")"

Note that the lexical order is reversed there, because the commands will be executed from innermost to outermost.  I find that harder to read, but it's a reasonable choice if you cannot rely on having the GNU version of xargs.

This might do what you want:
final_output=$(my-tool action1 -j "$json" | my-tool action2 -j "$(cat)" | my-tool action3 -j "$(cat)")


See What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable? for an explanation of why "$(cat)" is better than some alternatives for capturing input in a string.

I recommend that you do not use this code, or similar code.  The pipeline offers no performance advantage, makes error handling difficult, and compromises readability.  The approach demonstrated in the answer by @philippe is much better.
Another not-recommended way to do it is:
final_output=$(my-tool action3 -j "$(my-tool action2 -j "$(my-tool action1 -j "$json")")")


Note that this will work in bash, but not zsh, because in zsh the $( ) expression doesn't inherit its stdin from the command it's attached to, but from the outer context. This means it'll be reading from the terminal, rather than the pipe.

Thanks, this and the other responses have been very informative, I appreciate the different flavors of approach plus the bash/zsh comment for the purpose of learning.
